# Form with select and text options

Tags: html, django

I have an HTML form that needs to collect information entered into a text box as well as options that are chosen from a set of dropdown menus. To give a little context, I am creating virtual machines that can be configured by the user on a web page. They must enter a name (arbitrary) and a hostmachine in two separate boxes in addition to selecting options from three different dropdown menus. Because I am working with clusters, there could be as many as 99 "rows" of dropdown menus representing different system configurations that will be a part of the cluster.

Is it possible (if so, advisable?) to have both the text fields and the dropdowns contained in one form? If not, how do I make sure that the submit button sends *all* the data to my Django server for processing as I need all of this information to ultimately come to the same place.

I currently have them in different forms, but just ignore this for now as it doesn't do anything at the moment. Also don't worry about the lack of dropdowns present in this code as the addSelect() JS function is fully functional. Just know that each added node is given a unique name (node1, node2, etc.) and goes into the div "nodes".

```html
<body><b>Virtual Cluster Initialization</b><br></br>
        <div id="container">
        <div id="general">
                <form method="POST" id="naming">Cluster name:<br>
                <input type="text" name="cluster_name">
                <br>
                Host Machine:<br>
                <input type="text" name="host_machine">
                </form>
        </div>
        <form method="POST" id="node_config"></form>
        <div id="nodes" form="node_config"></div>
                <div id=node1">
                     <select name="node_type" id="node_type">Node Type</option>
                             (two options go here)
                     <select name="issp_version" id="issp_version>ISSP Version</option>
                             (7 or so options go here)
                     <select name="os" id="os">Operating System </option>
                             (about 20 options)
        <button id="add" onclick="addSelect('nodes');">+</button>
        </div>
        <br></br><input type="submit"></input>
</body>
```

EDIT1: Added the an example dropdown for clarity. Would it be better to NOT make a new div for each node? I did this initially because it seemed like a good way to keep each node's configuration separate. Like I said, there could be up to 99 nodes, each with three dropdown menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure if I understand what you're asking. Showing us the code after your drop downs are added would help. Syntax wise, this wont work. Inputs should be inside forms and div doesn't have a form property.

Put everything into one form if you want it to all be in one post. If your dynamically adding new form elements you can use an array as element names.

How about something like this?

```
  <script>
    var nodeID = 0;

    function addSelect() {
        var html = "<div id='node_" + nodeID + "'>";
        html += "<select name='node_type[" + nodeID + "]' id='node_type'><option>example</option></select>";
        html += "<select name='issp_version[" + nodeID + "]' id='issp_version'><option>ISSP Version</option></select>";
        html += "<select name='os[" + nodeID + "]' id='os'><option>Operating System </option></select>";
        html += "</div>";

        document.getElementById('nodes').innerHTML += html;
        nodeID++;
    }
</script>
<div style="margin-bottom:20px;"><b>Virtual Cluster Initialization</b>
</div>
<form>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="general">
            <div>Cluster name:</div>
            <div>
                <input name="cluster_name" type="text">
            </div>
            <div>Host Machine:</div>
            <div>
                <input name="host_machine" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="nodes">
            <div>Nodes</div>

            <div id="node_0">
                <select name="node_type[0]" id="node_type"><option>example</option></select>
                <select name="issp_version[0]" id="issp_version"><option>ISSP Version</option></select>
                <select name="os[0]" id="os"><option>Operating System </option></select>
            </div>
            <div id="node_1">
                <select name="node_type[1]" id="node_type"><option>example</option></select>
                <select name="issp_version[1]" id="issp_version"><option>ISSP Version</option></select>
                <select name="os[1]" id="os"><option>Operating System </option></select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="button" id="add" onclick="addSelect();">+</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is a JSfiddle to help you visualize what this does: 
https://jsfiddle.net/fdss08w9/2/

Example of how you might use this in Django:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # Get the number of nodes we added

            for id, node_type in enumerate(form.cleaned_data['node_type']):
                issp_version = form.cleaned_data['issp_version'][id]
                os = form.cleaned_data['os'][id]

                #do stuff with node_type, issp_version, os
```

Comment: Added an example dropdown. Can the indexing you did work with div names too, or only names within a div?

Comment: Updated my answer with a JSFiddle to what I think your asking. The indexing works on form elements: input, select, textarea, checkbox...ect. Divs wont show up in your POST data so using indexing on div names wouldnt do much for you. Indexing does work on divs though if you want to use javascript.

Comment: Yea this answers my question. I guess I was just unsure of how forms work in HTML since I've been using it, JS, and Django for less than a week. I now am at a point where I can retrieve my POST data and send it to my view.

Now to figure out how to manipulate these items since they are dynamically named

Comment: I updated my answer to include how you might do it in Django. Don't take my word for it though as I haven't done it in years.

Comment: Thanks! You've been extremely helpful. Don't know what I'd do without this place